# Can a locally defined holomophic function which vanishes on a subvariety $V$ be written in terms of globally defined polynomials vanishing on $V$?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Given a complex algebraic, affine variety $X$ and a subvariety $V$, let $I_V$ indicate the ideal of polynomials on $X$ with vanish on $V$.

Given an open subset $U$ of $X$, is it true that the ideal of holomorphic functions on $U$ which vanish on $V\cap U$ is generated by $I_V$?

Comment: holomorphic functions will probably not be generated by polynomials. did you mean regular functions on $U$?

Comment: To clarify, I meant that every holomorphic function on U which vanishes on $V$ may be written as a sum of holomorphic functions times polynomials in $I_V$.

Comment: I see. That makes more sense. Perhaps you should edit the question...(say add the ring in which you are working).

Answer (score 2):

This is true. Alex Isaev pointed out to me that it is Theorem 4.6 from `A geometric criterion for algebraic varieties' by Rudin.   A local version is  proposition 4 of Serre's GAGA paper.